# Cloudformation - Create resources in different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm actually using a Cloudformation stack in Francfurt region. I wanted to create 2 SSL certificates, and validate them. I suceeded, however I discovered later that I can't use them with my Cloudfront distribution as they need to be created in N. Virginia.

Now I'm facing this problem. How to create a resource in a different region ? I'm aware that a Cloudformation stack can only create resources in its own region, however, while searching for some solutions, I saw different persons mentioning Cloudformation StackSets.

I took a quick look, but I'm still questioning, can it really solve my issue ?

From what I've read, it seems it allows to create identical resources in different regions. But it doesn't seem that from one stack, create some resources in a region, and some others in another.

Can someone experimented with Cloudformation StackSets notice me if it is possible or not ?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

StackSets does not help in this case as it is used to create the same stack in multiple regions.

However, you can use [Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-%20customresource.html), which provides a way for you to write custom provisioning logic in CloudFormation template. A Lambda function can be triggered by Cloudformation, which creates the certificates in us-east-1 region by using one of the AWS SDKs.

Comment: Late reply, but for some looking at this post and wanting to know, yes, Custom Resources are the solution. I implemented one and that did the trick.